# Counterexample in a consequence of the Ergorrof Theorem

Tags: measure-theory

I proved that

> Suppose $E\in \mathcal{F}$, $E$  has $\sigma$-finite measure, $f_n$ ($n=1,2,\ldots$) and $f$ are finite a.e on $E$ and $f\rightarrow f_n$ a.e on $E$. Show that there exist a sequence $\{E_i\}$ of sets in $\mathcal{F}$ such that 
>   $$\mu\left(E\setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)=0 $$
>   uniformly on each $E_i$.

Now I want to prove that $E$ being $\sigma$-finite is a essential condition.

I have a hinṭ̣:

> Considerer $\mathbb{R}$ with the this measure, given $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ lets define $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is of first category and $\mu(A)=+\infty$ is of second category.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is of second category, then $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

But I don't know what to do next. Any hint?

Comment: I found this: $$\mu\left(E\backslash \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)=0 $$ I changed it to this: $$\mu\left(E\setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)=0 $$ The latter is standard usage.

Comment: I don't think that hint defines a measure...

Comment: @Ian you're right. Edited